# SQL delete statement deletes instead of error out

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone explain how this query even executes? The column `credit_transaction_key` does not exist in `financial_transaction`, but it does exist in `financial_transaction_jnl`. What I don't get is why this query even executes if the column is in one table but not the other table. Shouldn't this just error out?

```
delete from financial_transaction_jnl
where credit_transaction_key in 
      (select credit_transaction_key
       from financial_transaction
       where account_key in 
             (select account_key
              from account
              where created_by = (select USER_KEY
                                  from USERS 
                                  where USER_ID = 'ME')
                and created_dttm > Cast('2/16/2017' as datetime)
             )
      )
```

financial_transaction:
   financial_transaction_key account_key

financial_transaction_jnl:
   financial_transaction_jnl_key financial_transaction_key credit_transaction_key

Comment: Show the table structure for Financial_transaction.  I'm having trouble with the statement it doesn't exist.  But note, coorlated subqueries can reference columns within 1 level of the subquery.  So perhaps it's reaching back to financial_transaction_jrnl and using that value as a cross join between financial_transaction_jrnl and financial_transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The column `credit_transaction_key` does not exist in `financial_transaction`, but it does exist in `financial_transaction_jnl`. [...] Shouldn't this just error out?

No.  If indeed `financial_transaction` does not contain a column named `credit_transaction_key` then in the subquery that identifier will be resolved against the column list of the outer row set (i.e. the columns of `financial_transaction_jnl`) for the current row.  Since the value selected is therefore the same value that is being compared against the selection, the query you present has the same effect as this slightly simpler one:

```
delete from financial_transaction_jnl
where exists (
  SELECT 1
  from financial_transaction
  where account_key in (
    select account_key
    from account
    where created_by = (SELECT USER_KEY  FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = 'ME')
      AND created_dttm > Cast('2/16/2017' AS DATETIME)
  )
)
```

Inasmuch as the `WHERE` clause of the outer query therefore appears not to depend on the values in its target table, either all rows or none will be deleted.  That seems unlikely to be the desired effect.

Qualifying the column name in the outer query, as another answer suggests, will not alter this meaning.  Qualifying the column name in the *inner* query as `financial_transaction.credit_transaction_key` would indeed cause the query to error out.

Comment: If this is the case then it is really stupid how that works. But I will accept it.

Comment: @LetUsSeng, the semantics clearly caught you by surprise, but they are by no means stupid.  It is common that a subquery must refer to values from the context row of its containing query; this even has a name: a *correlated* subquery.  The way that plays out in your particular example is unhelpful, but it is a well-known, well-established, and overall useful feature of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use table aliases.

SQL has to assume where your columns are coming from.

in this case, everything gets deleted:

```
financial_transaction.redit_transaction_key in
(SELECT credit_transaction_key from  financial_transaction
```

but you are probably trying to do this:

```
financial_transaction_jnl.redit_transaction_key in
    (SELECT credit_transaction_key from  financial_transaction
```